# KIVY file falilure

Tags: python, visual-studio, kivy

I am new to kivy and don't know much about python. I try to run this code but it is showing an error now please help to run this code here is my code

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

class MyApp (App):
    def build(self):
        MyAnchor = AnchorLayout
        bttn1 = Button (
            text = "Hello World",
            size = (100, 100),
            pos = (50,50)
        )
        MyAnchor.add_widget(bttn1)

if __name__ =='__main__':
    MyApp().run()# Here is they are complaining
```

Here is the output:

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\DELL\.kivy\logs\kivy_22-06-25_4.txt
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.angle" 0.3.2
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.3.1
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.4.5
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.1.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.9.6 (tags/v3.9.6:db3ff76, Jun 28 2021, 15:26:21) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe"
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge log fired. Processing...
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge finished!
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 189 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <glew>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'4.3.0 - Build 20.19.15.4835'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Intel'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Intel(R) HD Graphics 4400'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 4, 3
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'4.30 - Build 20.19.15.4835'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <32>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...
PS C:\Python> & C:/Users/DELL/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe c:/Python/Kivy/Main.py
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\DELL\.kivy\logs\kivy_22-06-25_5.txt
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.angle" 0.3.2
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.3.1
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.4.5
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.1.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.9.6 (tags/v3.9.6:db3ff76, Jun 28 2021, 15:26:21) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe"
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge log fired. Processing...
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge finished!
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 189 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <glew>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'4.3.0 - Build 20.19.15.4835'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Intel'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Intel(R) HD Graphics 4400'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 4, 3
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'4.30 - Build 20.19.15.4835'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <32>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...
PS C:\Python> & C:/Users/DELL/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe c:/Python/Kivy/Main.py
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\DELL\.kivy\logs\kivy_22-06-25_6.txt
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.angle" 0.3.2
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.3.1
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.4.5
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.1.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.9.6 (tags/v3.9.6:db3ff76, Jun 28 2021, 15:26:21) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe"
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge log fired. Processing...
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge finished!
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 189 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
PS C:\Python> & C:/Users/DELL/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe c:/Python/Kivy/Main.py
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\DELL\.kivy\logs\kivy_22-06-25_45.txt
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.angle" 0.3.2
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.3.1
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.4.5
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.1.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.9.6 (tags/v3.9.6:db3ff76, Jun 28 2021, 15:26:21) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe"
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge log fired. Processing...
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge finished!
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 189 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] GLEW initialization succeeded
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <glew>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'4.3.0 - Build 20.19.15.4835'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Intel'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Intel(R) HD Graphics 4400'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 4, 3
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'4.30 - Build 20.19.15.4835'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <32>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "c:\Python\Kivy\Main.py", line 19, in <module>
     MyApp().run()
   File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", 
line 954, in run
     self._run_prepare()
   File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", 
line 924, in _run_prepare
     root = self.build()
   File "c:\Python\Kivy\Main.py", line 16, in build
     MyAnchor.add_widget(bttn1)
 TypeError: add_widget() missing 1 required positional argument: 'widget'
PS C:\Python>
```

how to run this code please help meeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee

Comment: Please don't keep adding rubbish into your question such as "please help meeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee" - that will be perceived as noise and isn't going to make people more likely to write you an answer.

Comment: I am very sorry I am new to this stack overflow I'll be taking the correction one my next question thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just a couple simple errors. Your line:

```
MyAnchor = AnchorLayout
```

does not create an instance of `MyAnchor`, it just sets `MyAnchor` to be a reference to `AnchorLayout`.

And your `build()` method does not return anything.

Here is a corrected version of your code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class MyApp (App):
    def build(self):
        MyAnchor = AnchorLayout()  # added ()
        bttn1 = Button (
            text = "Hello World",
            size = (100, 100),
            pos = (50,50)
        )
        MyAnchor.add_widget(bttn1)
        return MyAnchor  # added return

if __name__ =='__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

See the [build method documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable-2.0.0/api-kivy.app.html#kivy.app.App.build).